# Privacy settings do not allow shortcut to load external web content

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app, mobile-safari

Since updating to iOS 17, some of my Shortcuts fail to work on some web pages in Safari (only). For example I have a shortcut to use Mail to send the current webpage to me, but now on about have the websites where I attempt to use it, I get an error I've never seen before:

> The web content could not be loaded because your privacy settings do not allow this shortcut to load external web content. You can change this in the Privacy tab of the shortcut's settings.

[image]

On the Shortcut's privacy tab I've got Safari (were there always two entries?) configured to Always Allow, which is clearly respected for the pages that work so that's not the issue. (In fact I've reset the Shortcut's privacy several times to be sure.)

[image]

Why am I getting this message? What can I do to prevent the error and restore my Shortcut's functionality?

Comment: See if you can delete the one with the framework icon first. If no change in behaviour, delete the one with the proper Safari icon and rebuild the privacy settings.

Comment: @IconDaemon There’s no way to delete items other than resetting completely, which I’ve done several times. After the most recent, the framework one is gone, but the issue remains.

Comment: Maybe a Safari setting is causing the problem? You can always [file a bug report](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone/) with Apple. This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/10kxku5/clip_article_to_notes_shortcut_privacy_and/?rdt=59170) (at the bottom in a post by BigRigButters111) indicates this problem existed in the developer beta of iOS 17. This [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7ua-3XFSRw) may have a solution, too.

Comment: Just filed a feedback myself, same issue here. I'm not certain, but the framework icon may be from in-app webview, but haven't tested. Same problem happens in both webviews and the actual Safari app.

Answer (score 0):

I was puzzled with this error too. But in my case I managed to make it work using “get article” command like this. [image]

Comment: Can you explain how that's related?

Comment: If you need to get contents of a webpage sent to you, you may try fetching that information this way. Just input the link and use “get article” command and send that to your inbox.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).